# Measuring Latency between my local network hops

Tags: networking, ping, latency

I have to measure the latency in my local network and also between each hop. I used the conventional tools like ping, tracert, pathping etc. But the problem is here these tools have there own protocol overhead involved which may contribute to the measured latency.
So my question is there any way where I just simply send 10,000 packets and measure the latency. I was thinking of TCP but then it also have a protocol header with each packet? Any suggestion would be helpful.
Cheers!

Comment: That depends which latency exactly you want to measure - switch (L2), host-to-host (L3), process-to-process (L4), application (L7).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have to measure the host-to-host layer 3 latency. Between 5G UE devices, 5G cells and 5G core server for network testing.

Comment: Ping uses ICMP, which is an integral part of IP (layer-3).

Comment: It may help to also understand why you feel it’s so important to avoid protocol overhead entirely.  If anything, I would expect you to want to keep the overhead in order to more closely simulate real-world traffic than be some kind of perfect-world unrealistic test.

Comment: Hi @JesseP. , you have a valid point but my prof. have this requirement and he want something more accurate latency measurement tool or way because these above mentioned tools are just give a expected and some time varied RTT.

Comment: Also ICMP is not that reliable. So I was thinking to send like multiple SYN packets of TCP and figure out the SYN/ACK respond from the server using Wireshark. Is that work or make sense?

Comment: @nifty Okay, well, I need to let you know then that your question is now off limits here because it’s part of a test or school coursework.  I’m not sure how the mods are going to respond now that we know that part.

Comment: @JesseP. OKay no issues, I will figure that out. Thank you for your time

Comment: @nifty Do you mean something like how NPing or TCPing work, where they only perform the first 2 stages of a TCP handshake and measures that latency before sending an RST to close the half-open connection?  If so, how is that meeting your criteria given that TCP has its own overhead (as small as it may be)?

Comment: @JesseP. like how hping tool work (I did not read about NPing and TCPing that is why I am mentioning hping) where you are able send multiple SYN packets and also create a packet of your type which should so small as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest monitoring TCP RTT with productive traffic. This ensures realistic figures and prevents any probing artifacts.

For a one-shot measurement, TCPing or Nping (with appropriate parameters) should give the results you need. While those include L4 processing overhead, that is very much negligible with somewhat modern hosts.

Note that the above methods measure round-trip time (RTT), which is the sum of the latencies in each direction. Measuring true one-way latency is not trivial at all. Usually both ways are symmetric and halving the RTT is a very good approximation.